# How to Insert Latest Record and Inactive the other Record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  sample  Data

```
ID Name   val  Active 
1  Mohan  5     1
2  Mohan  10    1
```

I want  to clone  the  record  when I ran the  query every time

```
ID Name   val  Active 
1  Mohan  5     0
2  Mohan  10    0
3  Mohan  5     1
4  Mohan  10    1
```

Query

```
Update Table  SET  Active  = 0 WHERE  Name = 'Mohan'

INSERT INTO TABLE(ID,Name,val,Active )
SELECT  ID,Name,val,1FROM TABLE WHERE  Name = 'Mohan'
```

when I ran again this  same  query it is  inserting  4  records  I just want to insert  latest  Inactive  records as  Active  (i.e. 2 Records )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2 queries may be replaced with one

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(ID, Name, val, Active)
SELECT  ID, Name, val, 0
FROM TABLE 
WHERE Name = 'Mohan'
  AND Active = 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63c5ab48b67e52b81d396f63d21e33d7)

Comment: fine  with the conditions  but I execute  the query again it  will insert 4 records  I just want  to make  latest  2 records  to make Inactive and Insert 2 records  as  active

Comment: @mohan111 *but I execute the query again it will insert 4 records* I don't believe. 1st execute does not increase the amount of rows with `Active = 1` so 2nd execute MUST insert 2 rows again.

Comment: @mohan111 Fiddle added - and it agrees with me.

Comment: For example  table  have  2 active records and I have  executed  update and Insert for 1st time it will make 2 records inactive and 2 new records  will insert . When Next time execute same query it is  inserting 4 records

Comment: @mohan111 The fiddle provided is independent and confirmed fact. Your words are unconfirmed words only, they only prove that you did something wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join` to generate the rows:

```
select 'Mohan' as n.name, v.val, a.active
from (select distinct active from t) a cross join
     (select distinct val from t) v ;
```

It is unclear whether `id` is something you want to actually pass in.  If so, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by name, val, active) as id,
       'Mohan' as n.name, v.val, a.active
from (select distinct active from t) a cross join
     (select distinct val from t) v ;
```